# Binding an specific context to an event handler

Tags: javascript

I am just learning JavaScript and reading from that Ninja Secrets book and this is how he has done it to bind a click event to a button.  So as I am just a beginner and learning I wanted to do is it the best and final way of doing this ( adding click handler to a button ) or he has just used this as an example to demonstrate closures and this is NOT how in real world it is done.

```
  <body>
    <button id="test">Click Me!</button>

    <script>
      function bind(context,name){                                 //#1
        return function(){                                         //#1
          return context[name].apply(context,arguments);           //#1
        };                                                         //#1
      }                                                            //#1

      var button = {
        clicked: false,
        click: function(){
          this.clicked = true;
          assert(button.clicked,"The button has been clicked");
          console.log(this);
        }
      };

      var elem = document.getElementById("test");
      elem.addEventListener("click",bind(button,"click"),false);     //#2

    </script>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's mostly explaining how this works for educational purposes. In modern ECMAScript 5 there's a native `Function.bind` [(docs here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) so you can do:

```
elem.addEventListener("click", button.click.bind(button), false);
```

Comment: ECMAScript 5 isn't supported by IE 7 and 8, right?  If I want my JS to work under IE7,8, then is there any other way too? I mean not using the way he does it and not the way you do it, some other third way?

Comment: You can use the HTML5 shim to get this to work on older IE: https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/. It's javascript, there are maybe about a dozen variants of how to do this, but they all boil down to basically the same thing at the end of the day.

Comment: or maybe also using JQuery selector and saying its onclick event is that function.

Comment: @PeterLyons Why is he passing <code>arguments</code> parameter. is this needed ?

Comment: Yes, passing `arguments` will ensure any arguments the event emitter passes to the wrapper function get passed through to the bound function.